# std future exception - already retrieved, std bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, promise, std

I am trying to catch the Already-Retrieved exception as seen in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/future_errc/

```
try {
    prom.get_future();
    prom.get_future();   // throws std::future_error with future_already_retrieved
}
catch (std::future_error& e) {
    if (e.code() == std::make_error_condition(std::future_errc::future_already_retrieved))
        std::cerr << "[future already retrieved]\n";
    else
        std::cerr << "[unknown exception]\n";
}
```

But I always receive a no-state excpetion.
By looking at std future implementation:

```
_Ty& _Get_value() const
{   // return the stored result or throw stored exception
    if (!valid())   // will check if already retrieved, and return false
        _Throw_future_error(make_error_code(future_errc::no_state));
        return (_Assoc_state->_Get_value(_Get_only_once)); // only this
            // method can throw the already retrieved exception but its not
            // being hit because of previous valid() check
}
```

Is this a bug in Visual Studio 2013 or a feature?

Comment: You should look at the implementation of `std::promise` or `std::packaged_task` (specifically, the implementation of `std::promise::get_future` or `std::packaged_task::get_future`), not the one of `std::future`.

Comment: Yes, this looks like a Visual Studio bug to me.

Answer (score 4):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/get_future) which I find to be more reliable:

> Exception is thrown if *this has no shared state or get_future has already been called.

What exceptions?

> Throws: future_error if `*this` has no shared state or if get_future has already been called on a promise with the same shared state as *this.
>
> - (14.1) future_already_retrieved if get_future has already been called on a
>   promise with the same shared state as *this .
> - (14.2) no_state if *this has no shared state.

So this is a bug in MSVC2013.

Comment: But the OP isn't calling `future::get()`, `promise::get_future()` is completely a different function.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Hmm.  Not sure what I was thinking, but it was wrong.  Answer corrected.